# prepareForSegue called but not loading the next UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm dealing with an application with two UIViewControllers. When the application launches, the LoaderViewController is triggered. On that view controller, I am setting up the application for launch and then trying to move into ViewController. The problem is that the prepareForSegue method is called correctly, but it does nothing. I'm trying to do the navigation same way as i've done before. What is it i might be missing here? I'm still very new in iOS development.

```
 class LoaderViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var applicationLoadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()


      applicationLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToMenuViewController", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
      var vc: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController
  }
}
```

Here is the image of the storyboard:
[image]

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

Solution was to change the performSegueWithIdentifier call into viewDidAppear() method.

Comment: Could you also share a screenshot of your storyboard and how you named your segues?

Comment: Ofc! Added image for the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be segueing in `viewDidLoad` as that is way too soon. At the very least, you should instead segue in `viewDidAppear`.